# Azure multi-tenant ASP.Net-Core application with Bearer authorization

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, adal, bearer-token

How to setup Bearer authorization for multi-tenant application?

It is single page application. On browser site app use [Adal.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) to authenticate users. After authentication app send request to ASP.Net-Core server side with Authorization Bearer header.

ASP.Net-Core use [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/) to check request. Here is Startup:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
        {
            sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddAzureAdBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

        // ... other ...
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseAuthentication();

        // ... other ...
    }
}
```

Here is AddAzureAdBearer method:

```cs
public static class AzureAdServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static AuthenticationBuilder AddAzureAdBearer(this AuthenticationBuilder builder)
        => builder.AddAzureAdBearer(_ => { });
    public static AuthenticationBuilder AddAzureAdBearer(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, Action<AzureAdOptions> configureOptions)
    {
        builder.Services.Configure(configureOptions);
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<JwtBearerOptions>, ConfigureAzureOptions>();
        builder.AddJwtBearer();
        return builder;
    }
    private class ConfigureAzureOptions : IConfigureNamedOptions<JwtBearerOptions>
    {
        private readonly AzureAdOptions AzureOptions;
        public ConfigureAzureOptions(IOptions<AzureAdOptions> azureOptions)
        {
            AzureOptions = azureOptions.Value;
        }
        public void Configure(string name, JwtBearerOptions options)
        {
            options.Audience = AzureOptions.ClientId;

            // this works (specific TenantId)
            // options.Authority 
            //    = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/f8811864-6950-4347-af1c-9d22bb3d0615"
            // this did not work (common instead of specific TenantId)
            // options.Authority 
            //    = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";
            options.Authority = $"{AzureOptions.Instance}{AzureOptions.TenantId}";
        }
        public void Configure(JwtBearerOptions options)
        {
            Configure(Options.DefaultName, options);
        }
    }
 }
```

For single tenant this works as expected, it is possible to mark controller with [Authorize] attribute

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[Authorize]
public class CalendarController : Controller
{
```

For multi-tenant I set up Adal.js to common endpoint, and it is working (user can successfully login). But ASP.Net-Core server cannot check Bearer header, as for single tenant

JwtBearerOptions.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/f8811864-6950-4347-af1c-9d22bb3d0615"

For multi-tenant I try to sent up

JwtBearerOptions.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common"

ASP.Net-Core server return unauthorized response.

UPDATE

Post [The Common Endpoint: Walks Like a Tenant, Talks Like a Tenant… But Is Not a Tenant](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/08/26/the-common-endpoint-walks-like-a-tenant-talks-like-a-tenant-but-is-not-a-tenant/) describe the reason of the problem with common Authority.

In short: token (that send as a Authorization Bearer header and must be validated on a server side) contains "issuer" string like this: `https://sts.windows.net/<TENAT_ID>`. `<TENAT_ID>` - will be real `<TENAT_ID>` not a "common" string.

So, when Authorization Bearer header validated, "issuer" string compared with configured options.Authority setting.

To fix the problem it is possible to disable issuer validation. And make it yourself:

```cs
    public void Configure(string name, JwtBearerOptions options)
    {
        options.Audience = AzureOptions.ClientId;

        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters{
            ValidateIssuer = false
        };
        options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
        {
            OnTokenValidated = (context) =>
            {
                if(!context.SecurityToken.Issuer.StartsWith("https://sts.windows.net/"))
                    throw new SecurityTokenValidationException();

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        };

        options.Authority = $"{AzureOptions.Instance}{AzureOptions.TenantId}";
    }
```

I am not sure if it is correct way to check Issuer. Please let me know is it correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. For a multitenant application, set ValidateIssuer to false. That means the application will validate the issuer.

Validate the token issuer in the JwtBearerEvents.TokenValidated event. The issuer is sent in the "iss" claim.

```
public override async Task TokenValidated(TokenValidatedContext context)
{
    var principal = context.Ticket.Principal;
    var tenantManager = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<TenantManager>();
    var userManager = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<UserManager>();
    var issuerValue = principal.GetIssuerValue();
    var tenant = await tenantManager.FindByIssuerValueAsync(issuerValue);

    if (tenant == null)
    {
        // The caller was not from a trusted issuer. Throw to block the authentication flow.
        throw new SecurityTokenValidationException();
    }

    var identity = principal.Identities.First();

}
```

You can refer to this section of Microsoft Document for reference - [Authenticating in the web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/web-api#authenticating-in-the-web-api)

Comment: thank you. `tenantManager.FindByIssuerValueAsync()` is a custom method that check issuer by custom database. My App do not store allowed tenants list, so I cannot check issuer by database. Is it OK to check issuer is Microsoft authorization point like this `Issuer.StartsWith("https://sts.windows.net/")` ?

Answer (score 0):

This post here shows how to do custom issuer validation. https://thomaslevesque.com/2018/12/24/multitenant-azure-ad-issuer-validation-in-asp-net-core/

```
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";
                options.Audience = configuration["AzureAdSettings:ClientId"];
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true; // or false if you dont have https
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerValidator = (issuer, token, parameters) => issuer 
                   //allows any issuer or use `ValidateIssuerWithPlaceholder`
                };
            });
```

The post has this method to validate the token

```
private static string ValidateIssuerWithPlaceholder(string issuer, SecurityToken token, TokenValidationParameters parameters)
{
    // Accepts any issuer of the form "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}/v2.0",
    // where tenantid is the tid from the token.

    if (token is JwtSecurityToken jwt)
    {
        if (jwt.Payload.TryGetValue("tid", out var value) &&
            value is string tokenTenantId)
        {
            var validIssuers = (parameters.ValidIssuers ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>())
                .Append(parameters.ValidIssuer)
                .Where(i => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(i));

            if (validIssuers.Any(i => i.Replace("{tenantid}", tokenTenantId) == issuer))
                return issuer;
        }
    }

    // Recreate the exception that is thrown by default
    // when issuer validation fails
    var validIssuer = parameters.ValidIssuer ?? "null";
    var validIssuers = parameters.ValidIssuers == null
        ? "null"
        : !parameters.ValidIssuers.Any()
            ? "empty"
            : string.Join(", ", parameters.ValidIssuers);
    string errorMessage = FormattableString.Invariant(
        $"IDX10205: Issuer validation failed. Issuer: '{issuer}'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidIssuer: '{validIssuer}' or validationParameters.ValidIssuers: '{validIssuers}'.");

    throw new SecurityTokenInvalidIssuerException(errorMessage)
    {
        InvalidIssuer = issuer
    };
}
```

When you specify an **Authority** to the middleware it will automatically try to find the public keys to validate the token with as discussed here https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi-v2/issues/7

Comment: More details are here about the token validation process https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core/